# L2 convergence for a simple function approximation

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, almost-everywhere, simple-functions

Consider the problem on the picture. I am struggling with part (b) of the excercise. I have managed to show that we have $L^1$ convergence, but I am unable to show $L^2$ convergence. Does anyone have a slight hint sending me in the right direction? Thanks a lot!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $g \in L^{2}$ and $g$ is orthogonal to $I_{j,n}$ for all $n$ and $j$ then $g=0$ a.e..  By Hilbert space Theory this implies that linear combinations of the functions $I_{j,n}$  form a dense subspace of $L^{2}$. When $f$ is such a linear combination the result follows trivially (with $E_n=f$ for $n$ sufficiently large). The general case follows by approximating $f$ by a finite linear combination of the functions $I_{j,n}$ since $\|E_nf-E_ng\|\leq \|f-g\|$.

Comment: I feel like your assertion of $E_n = f$ for sufficiently large $n$ is false. Take $f$ to be the indicator of the set $\{ \frac12\}$. Then $E_n = 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: I am making  that claim in the case when $f$ is a finite linear combination  of the functions $I_{j,n}$. Also, your $f$ the zero element of $L^{2}$!. @PROB123

Comment: I misread your claim and I understand now. Could you elaborate on the last step with the estimation?

Comment: Never mind I got the answer myself