# Is the set of linear combinations of the functions $I_{j,n}$, $n \in \mathbb N$, dense in $L^{2}$?

Tags: functional-analysis

In the Q. 4265006 ([L2 convergence for a simple function approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4265006/l2-convergence-for-a-simple-function-approximation)) at his question related to   solve "Problem 2.19." (probable copied from a manual/book)
received the following solution:

Hint: If $g \in L^{2}(0,1)$ and $g$ is orthogonal to $I_{j,n}$ for all $n$ and $j$ then $g=0$ a.e.. By Hilbert space Theory this implies that linear combinations of the functions $I_{j,n}$ form a dense subspace of $L^{2}(0,1)$...
where  $I_{j,n} := (j/2^n, (j-1)/2^n) \subset (0,1)$.

My question:
Is the set of  linear combinations of the functions $I_{j,n}, j =1$, $n \in \mathbb N$ dense in  $L^{2}(0,1)$ ?
If so, where can I find the proof? Could someone provide a link (internet page or the book, author, etc. in order to access it?

I really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry,  should be  $I_{j,n} := (j/2^n, (j+1)/2^n) \subset (0,1)$,  $0 \leq  j  \leq 2^n - 1 $ . My mistake.

Comment: If $f$ is orthogonal to each of these then $f$ vanishes at all Lebesgue points of $f$ and hence $f=0$ a.e. This proves that linear combinations of these functions is dense.

Comment: So, elaborating the idea, if f verifies $ \int_0^1 f(x) \textbf{1}_{I_{j,n}}(x)dx =0$ for all $0 \leq j \leq 2^n -1, n \in N$, then f = 0 a.e. 

Rewriting, $ \int_{I_{j,n}} f(x)dx = 0 $ on all intervals from the family. How could obtain from here that f = 0 a.e. ?

Comment: Use the definition of Lebesgue point. Ref: Rudin's RCA.

Comment: Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem and the concept of intervals nicely shrinking to $x$ have to be used. Not more than 2-3 pages of Rudin's book are needed.

Comment: Could you indicate the pages needed to read please ?